# Java transpose matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, transpose

I wanted to transpose matrix in this way

I tried to create matrix then create a method for transposing it but, unfortunately, when i caled the function result was the same matrix as a first created

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the height of array: ");
        int height = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the width of array: ");
        int width = input.nextInt();

        int[][] array =  new int[height][width];
        int[][] transposed_matrix =  new int[width][height];
        Random rand_num = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                array[i][j]=rand_num.nextInt(1, 50);
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Transposed matrix: \n");
        transposeMatrix(array, transposed_matrix, height, width);
    }

    public static void transposeMatrix(int[][] array, int[][] transposed_matrix, int height, int width){
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                transposed_matrix[j][i] = array[i][j];
                System.out.print(transposed_matrix[j][i] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Expected output:
34  34  24  26
41  44  43  40
22  40  47  3

Transposed matrix:

34  41  22
34  44  40
24  43  47
26  40  3

actual output:

34  34  24  26
41  44  43  40
22  40  47  3

Transposed matrix:

34  34  24  26
41  44  43  40
22  40  47  3

Comment: You're just mixing up x and y on the second output, showing the transposed matrix in a transposed form, so that it looks like normal again.. So throw your code that does the printing into a method `printMatrix(int[][] pMatrix)`. (in the outer loop do `for(int y=0; y<pMatrix.length; y++)` and in the inner do `for(int x=0; x<pMatrix[y].length; x++)` so you dont need width/height, maybe interchange x and y if you like that more) And then run it on the 2 matrices, you'll see that you actually properly transposed the matrix already.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the *transposed_matrix*, in the same order as the *array*.

Print after the *for-loop*.

Here is an example.

```java
int i = 0, j;
do {
    j = 0;
    do transposed_matrix[j][i] = array[i][j];
    while (++j < width);
} while (++i < height);
for (int[] t : transposed_matrix) {
    i = 0;
    for (int e : t) {
        if (i++ != 0) System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or, use a *stream*.

```java
Stream.of(transposed_matrix).forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.stream(x)
              .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
              .collect(Collectors.joining("\t"))
    );
});
```

Output

```
Enter the height of array: 
4
Enter the width of array: 
4
30  46  3   46  
14  46  42  19  
42  3   24  12  
4   5   3   39  
Transposed matrix: 

30  14  42  4
46  46  3   5
3   42  24  3
46  19  12  39
```

Additionally, you can just swap the values.

```java
<T> void transpose(T[][] a) {
    int m = a.length, n = a[0].length;
    T t;
    for (int i = 0, j; i < m; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            t = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[j][i];
            a[j][i] = t;
        }
}
```